# Flutter: Stream not retrieving data from sub collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, riverpod

I am creating my own comment system.
I am using firebase to store the comments and then the replies into a subcollection.
My code is retrieving the main comments, but for some reason I can't get the sub comments.
Have double checked the path and everything.

My stream looks like this

```
    var retVal;
    try {
        retVal = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Challenges')
          .doc(challenge.id)
          .collection('comments')
          .doc(comment.id)
          .collection('SubComments')
          .orderBy(CommentField.createdTime, descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .transform(Utils.transformer<Comment>(Comment.fromJson));
      return retVal;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e)
    {
      print(e.toString());
      return retVal;

    }
  }
```

(mind the var and other weird stuff. Was trying to see if i can catch a error, but no luck)

Code where I call the stream using Riverpod.

```
final challengeSubCommentStreamProvider =
StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<List<Comment>, ReadSubCommentClass>((ref, parameters) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database.readSubComments(parameters.challenge, parameters.comment);
});

    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ScopedReader watch, child){
        final userDataProvider = watch(userProvider);
        final user = userDataProvider.user;
        final ReadSubCommentClass parameters = ReadSubCommentClass(challenge: widget.challenge, comment: widget.comment!);
        final challengeSubCommentStream = watch(challengeSubCommentStreamProvider(parameters));
        return challengeSubCommentStream.when(
            data: (comments) {
              if(comments.isNotEmpty)
              return SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, int index){
                    return buildReplyCommentListTile(comments[index], user);
                  },
                  childCount: comments.length,
                ),
              );
              else return Container(color: Colors.blue,);
            },
            loading: () => SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: Text('Loading'),)),
            error: (_,__) => SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container()));
      },
    );
```

Picture from Firestore to depict path
Challenges/{ChallengeID}/comments/{CommentID}/SubComments

[image]
The code is just stuck at Loading and not getting any values.

Comment: So im 100% sure it's getting data since if i halt at transformer i see it looping between the 2 documents i have there. So it's just stuck at loading

Comment: Is there any chance that your stream is never returning data? I know you said it's getting data, but being stuck in loading would be a symptom of your stream not being returned. Maybe try taking out the transformer and see if just the raw firebase data can be returned as a stream?

Comment: Checked all that, Problem was initializing parameters value for some reason. Even though i saw in transformer that i got the correct data from firebase

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the way I was initializing

```
final ReadSubCommentClass parameters = ReadSubCommentClass(challenge: widget.challenge, comment: widget.comment!);
```

After I moved it to initState() it started working and I get output on UI